# How to refer/assign policies to cdk objects created from an array

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I would like to assign iam policies to sns topics whose ARNs are in an array.

For example:

```
const TopicArns = [
'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678901:topic1',
'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678901:topic2',
'arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:12345678901:topic3'
]

const defaultTopicPolicystatement = new iam.PolicyStatement({
      sid: "some_sid",
      actions: ["sns:Publish"],
      principals: [
        new iam.CompositePrincipal(
          new iam.ArnPrincipal(principal1),   \\these principals are variables set previous.
          new iam.ArnPrincipal(principal2)
        ),
      ],
      resources: ["*"],
    });
```

Now, I would like to iterate through the list and assign the default policy to those ARNs.  I have tried a number of ways, but I can't figure out the neatest way to do it, without creating an iam policy document specific to each and every arn.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: `const ppls = TopicArns.map(it => new ArnPrincipal(it));` `ppls.forEach(it => it.something())` then use that array in `new CompositePrincipal`? Or is the method for setting the policy somewhere else? Cdk allows you to use loops and have arrays of things.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding; not trying to loop through array for the composite principal.  Trying to loop through the array to assign the default profile to all of the objects (sns topics) in the array.

Comment: Then what about `const statements: PolicyStatement[] = TopicArns.map(arn => new PolicyStatement(... new iam.ArnPrincipal(arn) ...)`?